On the orthogonality relations for quantum Clebsch-Gordan coefficients
I am currently reading Quantum groups by Christian Kassel, more precisely, section VII.7 which is about quantum Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.
To make this question self-contained, let me introduce the notation. We consider the quantized universal enveloping algebra $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ which is an associative algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$) with generators $E,F,K,K^{-1}$ and the following relations:
$$
KK^{-1}=K^{-1}K=1, KEK^{-1}=q^2E,KFK^{-1}=q^{-2}F, EF-FE=\frac{K-K^{-1}}{q-q^{-1}},
$$
where $q$ is a complex parameter and we assume that $q$ is non-zero and not a root of unity.
To get a Hopf algebra, let us define the comultiplication map, i.e. an algebra isomorphism $\Delta\colon U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)\otimes U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)\otimes$ defined via
$$
\Delta(E)=1\otimes E+E\otimes K,\Delta(F)=K^{-1}\otimes F+F\otimes 1,\Delta(K)=K\otimes K,\Delta(K^{-1})=K^{-1}\otimes K^{-1}.
$$
We also have the counit, i.e. an algebra homomorphism $\varepsilon\colon U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2\to\mathbb{C}$ defined on generators as follows:
$$
\varepsilon(E)=\varepsilon(F)=0,\varepsilon(K)=\varepsilon(K^{-1})=1.
$$
(There is also the antipode, i.e. an algebra anti-homomorpism $S\colon U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2\to U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$, but we will not use it here.)
Let $V(n)$ be the simple $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$-module of the highest weight $n$ (in particular, $\dim V(n)=n+1$). We denote by $v^{(n)}=v^{(n)}_{0}$ the corresponding highest weight vector and let $v^{(n)}_{j}=\frac{1}{[j]!}F^{j}v^{(n)}$, where $[j]=\frac{q^j-q^{-j}}{q-q^{-1}}$. Kassel introduces a pairing $(\cdot,\cdot)$ defined via
$$
(v^{(n)}_{i},v^{(n)}_{j})=\delta_{ij}q^{-i(n-1-i)}\cdot\frac{[n]!}{[i]![n-i]!}.
$$
Then, there is a $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$-decomposition:
$$
V(n)\otimes V(m)\simeq V(n+m)\oplus V(n+m-2)\oplus\ldots\oplus V(|n-m|).
$$
Note that tensor products of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$-modules get the $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$-structure via $\Delta$.
In the book, Kassel proves this by checking that if $n\geq m$, then vectors
$$
v^{(n+m-2p)}=\sum_{i=0}^{p}(-1)^{i}\frac{[m-p+i]![n-i]!}{[m-p]![n]!}q^{-i(m-2p+i+1)}v^{(n)}_{i}\otimes v^{(m)}_{p-i}
$$
are highest weight vectors of weight $q^{m+n-2p}$ (and then compare the dimensions).
Then, Kassel aims to obtain certain orthogonality relations for quantum Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, i.e. for the entries of the transition matrix between basis $\{v^{(n)}_{i}\otimes v^{(m)}_{j}\}_{i,j}$ and $\{v^{(n+m-2p)_{l}}\}_{l,p}$. In order to do so, he defines a pairing on $V(n)\otimes V(m)$ by means of
$$
(v_1\otimes v_1',v_2\otimes v_2')=(v_1,v_2)\cdot(v_1',v_2').
$$
Then, he checks that both bases are orthogonal with respect to the introduced pairing on the tensor product, see Proposition VII.7.5. However, he seems to use the fact that
$$
(v^{(n+m-2p)},v^{(n+m-2p)})=1
$$
but does not explain that. Note that this is not needed for orthogonality of different vectors, but it is required for computing the norms of these vectors.

Question. Is it true that $(v^{n+m-2p},v^{(n+m-2p)})=1$? (If not, then Proposition VII.7.5 is likely to be incorrect.)

Not only I am not able to prove it myself, I am now start to suspect that this might not be true! Using the definitions above, the required equality is equivalent to (unless my computations are incorrect)
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{p}\frac{[m]![m-p+i]![n-i]!}{[m-p]!^2[n]![i]![p-i]!}q^{-p(m-1-p)-i(n+m-2p+2)}=1,
$$
which does not hold even for $p=1$.
Remark. In any case, if someone could point out another reference for the quantum Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, it would be greatly appreciated.

A TeX-question: I am not sure how I can write q-binomial coefficients (like binomial, but with square brackets), so I wrote a fraction in the definition of the pairing. Feel free to edit this accordingly.

I don't see where the equality $(v^{(n+m-2p)},v^{(n+m-2p)})=1$ is used/needed in the Proposition. Could you point to it?

@DanielArreola Yes, sure. At the very end of the proof of part (b) of Proposition VII.7.5, Kassel writes "On the other hand, $(v^{(n+m-2p)}{k},v^{(n+m-2q)}{l})=\ldots$". It is not difficult to show that in order to prove this it suffices to check the identity for $k=l=0$ and $p=q$ only. However, I failed to verify this.
